# Laplace-Beltrami Operator defined in Conformal Flow of Metrics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, vector-analysis, laplacian

I am looking at the [following article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0067.pdf): on page 5 the authors define a conformal flow of metrics, one of the conditions of which is that

$\Delta_{g_t} v_t =0 \: \: \text{on} \:\: M_t.$

Later on page 11 as an explicit example, the authors give as an example

$v_t = \frac{-e^{-t} + \frac{M}{2r}e^t}{e^{-t} + \frac{M}{2r}e^t}.$

I am not sure what I am missing here, but I don't see how the Laplace-Beltrami operator of this function would vanish to zero.  One can compute for example

$\frac{\partial^2 v_t}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2v_t}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 v_t}{\partial z^2} = \frac{16 M e^{2t}}{(2 r + M e^{2t})^3},$

as only some of the terms cancel out.  Are we assuming that certain terms vanish?
The metric for the Laplace-Beltrami operator is $g_t = u_t^4 g$, where in this explicit example $g$ is the spatial Schwarzchild metric in Cartesian coordinates (equation 3.13) and $u_t$ is given in equation 3.14

$u_t = \frac{e^{-t} + \frac{M}{2r}e^t}{1+ \frac{M}{2r}}.$

However, I still don't see how there is supposed to be a cancellation of terms to zero if one considers the Laplace-Beltrami operator as the trace of the Hessian tensor.

Comment: I would have thought that the use of $r$ implied the author is assuming the solution [is radially symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation#Forms_in_different_coordinate_systems) so that $$\Delta (\cdot) = \frac{1}{r} \partial_{r} \left( r \partial_{r} (\cdot) \right)$$

Comment: You only gave half of the necessary data. What is $g_t$ here? Your computation seems to assume that it is $dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$ in these coordinates.

Comment: More information added.